# dynamic import returns {$$typeof:...,render:f...} instead of the exported class

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am using nextjs and trying to import the module `Quill` into my project using this code

```
const Quill = dynamic(import("quill") , {
    ssr:false,
})
```

but when i log `Quill` this is result `{$$typeof:...,render:f...}` instead of the Quill class

and this is the vanilla-js module and i am trying to make it compatible with nextjs
at start i used the react-quill module but faced problems with getting more control over the editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so this is my solution i uninstalled this module and installed `react-quill`

but i imported it in a way that the editor can be used and the component will be rendered

so first in the components directory i created two files

```
-ReactQuill
-ReactQuillWrapper
```

i wrote my component normally like a client side rendered react component and here is the code

```
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import { useRef , useCallback } from "react";

function ReactQuillEditor({Ref , formats , theme , modules , placeHolder}) {

    return (
        <ReactQuill ref={Ref}  theme={theme} modules={modules} placeholder={placeHolder} ></ReactQuill>
    )
}

export default ReactQuillEditor
```

then i exported this with a rapper to loaded dynamically in the client side

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

using this code

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";


const ReactQuill = dynamic(import("./ReactQuill"), {    
    ssr: false,
    })

export default ReactQuill
```

and finally in my page

```
import {useState , useRef, useEffect , useCallback} from "react"
import ReactQuill from '../components/ReactQuillWrapper'

import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css'

export default function Blog() {

        let ReactQuillRef = useCallback(editor => {
            editor?.editor?.format('direction', 'rtl');
            editor?.editor?.format('align', 'right');
        })
        
const module = {toolbar:[

    [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown

    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike' , 'link'],        // toggled buttons
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
    [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
    [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ 'align': [] }],
    
    ['image'],

    ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
],}

return (
<>
<div></div>
<ReactQuill Ref={ReactQuillRef} modules={module} placeHolder={"هرچی دوست داری بنویس ..."} ></ReactQuill>
</> 
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just answering here because I don't have a reputation to upvote or comment. But the above solution by "mahdi tajik" is pretty good. I was struggling for past 2 days and after a lot of experimenting, makeshifting and googling I found this. And, this was such a simple and clean solution to the problem of dynamic imports.

I don't know if anyone would get this but "Devta manus nikla re tu toh!"

I'll explain my problem a bit. I was trying to use Quill from react-quill dynamically.

```
import { Quill } from 'react-quill';

// Later somewhere
Quill.register([SOME_FORMAT]);
```

And it became impossible to get this done dynamically.

So, thanks to solution above, I created a LazyWrapper for the whole component and used it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35699524)